# Determine the sign of : $2amx^{2m-1}(-x^3+y^3) + 2bny^{2n-1}(-x^3-y^3)$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality

I'm having a bit of a hard time determining the sign, as asked :

> Determine the sign of : $$2amx^{2m-1}(-x^3+y^3) + 2bny^{2n-1}(-x^3-y^3)$$
>
> where $a,b \in \mathbb R$ and $m,n \in \mathbb Z^+$.

By expanding it, we'd get :

$$-2amx^{2m+2} + 2amx^{2m-1}y^3-2bnx^3y^{2n-1}-2bny^{2n+2}$$

Obviously, the terms $-2amx^{2m+2}$ and $-2bny^{2n+2}$ are determined from the sign of $a$ and $b$ respectively, since $x^{2m+2},y^{2n+2} \geq 0$ and $m,n \in \mathbb Z^+$.

But I can't see how to proceed on making conclusions for the rest or how I could continue.

I'd appreciate any help.